# Exit Kodi by pressing HOME button, is this safe?

Tags: android

Using Himedia TV box Q5 Pro with Android 5.1 and Kodi 17.1.

Instead of shutting down Kodi by using the screen exit button (which will take a few seconds), find it easier if I used the HOME button on the remote.

Will this HOME button exit route result in Kodi software problem later?

Appreciate the above program flow in using the HOME button and if that HOME route is not recommended, why?

Like to learn more on Android.

Many thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about programming, but about using some program.

Comment: How your question relates to programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem PLUMBERSO. If you'd like to know about App's Lifecycle and everything under the sun for Android I suggest going through Google's own set of tutorials and documentation.

https://developer.android.com/develop/index.html

TLDR: No. Unless Kodi was designed very badly and even then only in select circumstances...

If Kodi has a dedicated button you click to "Exit" it may be doing something in the background before quitting.

Having said that Android apps should not generally rely on the user doing a specific set of actions for saving stuff.

Android Apps have 4 main components: Activities, Content Providers, Broadcast Receivers and Services. Of all of them Activities are often the most common. Everything to do with the UI itself is borne of the Activity, and nothing else is supposed to touch the UI directly.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html documents the Activity lifecycle. A good Android Activity should basically be prepared to handle the most destructive of cases; ironically, that can happen on something as simple as a phone screen rotation. This basically triggers the entire lifecycle (onPause --> onStop --> onDestroy --> onCreate --> onStart --> onResume).

(Nearly) all apps on Android run on a single process (Linux). On pressing the home button Android sends that process into the background priority, and hence a "suspended" state for the Activity (onPause/onStop but not onDestroy). On pressing back, that particular Activity is "popped" off the stack maintaining the list of Activities the user has navigated through. No other component has such a "stack", and their usages are definitely not for the UI.

Content Providers generally interact with SQL/NoSQL databases, Broadcast Receivers for changes in phone state (broadcasted by the app to itself, or by the app to the whole phone, or by the phone to all apps etc.), Services for longer running tasks that should not be done on the Activity itself. There's a whole host of design patterns and combinations to handle intensive or network based work that helps hive the work off the UI thread and off the Activity lifecycle (which is really annoying to do if on the Activity itself).

Popping the Activity off the "stack" destroys it. Pressing the home button does not pop the stack; if you notice by clicking on an App, going to a page, then going home, then going back to the app, the screen you were on should be resumed. However, if the person "kills" it via the multitasking option in Android phones since Android 4, then the process is generally ended and the whole app is hence "dead". Click on the app icon again and you should find the app go back to it's original screen on launch.

So. If Kodi needs to do something that takes a while (eg. Interface with it's servers, save some data on your local storage etc) it should do so in other components, and immediately when the need is recognised. Maybe its trying to save something extra when you exit via it's dedicated exit button, but it should be programmed to do without those steps just fine.

Comment: Noted and many thanks!

Comment: No problem; if this helped answer your question please do mark it as the answer!

Comment: Noted and many thanks! Will try the Google docs on Android again (started with that last year). Found one good Android tutorial in Udemy. Testing the HOME option for the past few days. On returning to Kodi after pressing the HOME button, it brought me back to the Kodi screen where I pressed the HOME button. Looks like HOME is just pausing Kodi rather than an EXIT. Will pausing Kodi and later shutting down the TV box cause some damage to Kodi? Something for me to find out. Once again, many thanks for your help.

Comment: no problem, happy coding!